# What is Samba in simple terms?

Tags: audit

Well basically a couple of days ago I decided to go on Omegle and one of the people I met seemed to be a troll and some point said why is my Samba protocol open.

From this site they were able to get my IP.

However my only concern here is that can they gain remote access this way to my system and this samba thing allows it?

I might add that I was also only on this chat for about no longer than 1 - 2 minutes.

Thus I have also performed a multitude of scans and everything has come back clean.

I'd be very grateful for any info on this. thanks.

Comment: Samba does not try to allow it, but recently there has been a very nasty vulnerability in Samba, which allows anyone who can access your Samba port to gain full access to your system: http://badlock.org/

Comment: Most anti-malware scanners would detect this right if anyone had gained access? I have scanned with stuff such as MBAM, EMSISOFT and more.

Comment: No. In fact, I would say the chances any anti-malware scanners would detect access is exceptionally small. AV is practically a scam. It is good at detecting old or well known threats, and detecting threats which through sipmle heuristics. It is completely trivial to bypass AV with a minimal level of effort. In fact, you often have to make an effort to be *detected* by AV in the first place.

Comment: @forest AV is not a scam, it just has a very narrow use case. I wouldn't want to run a system without an AV, but I wouldn't trust the protection of the system to AV alone.

Comment: @user107111 your title question is asking what samba is, but the body of the question doesn't seem to be in line with that question. Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: @schroeder You're right. I would be better of saying, it scams many people out of their money, and most people do not use it correctly. But yes, it does have a valid use case. I would never run a system with an AV myself, because the attack surface area is just too high. The chance malware will take advantage of the AV to elevate privileges is much higher than the chance that the AV will catch malware which would otherwise evade me.

Answer (score 1):

Samba usually refers to the [*nix implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) of the [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) protocol.

Basically, it means you have a machine that is either directly connected to the net or has it's IP forwarded in your firewall and that has file or printers sharing enabled.

Whether that service can be remotely exploited (in any way) depends a lot on what's your actual setup it. However, finding an open SMB server usually is a sign of poor security since it's not a protocol that is commonly shared across public network.

Comment: From performing a diagnostic scan the only port that I see open is 139 and that relates to a virtual machines that I have installed on my system. As for my security setup well you can never have too much security but I do have a rather high security setup.